# getting all checked boxes in a twig view and use them in a session

Tags: php, symfony, session, twig

I am working with Symfony / twig.

I have a collection named ***GroupesOfCompetences*** which contains many ***GroupeOfCompetence***. 
Each  ***GroupeOfCompetence*** contains a collection of ***competences***

I would like to be able to get all the ***competences*** that are checked in a form, whose code is :

```
<form action="{{ path('app_profil_traitement_competences') }}" method="post">

    {% set i = 1 %}

    {% for GroupeOfCompetence in GroupesOfCompetences %}
    name of the group of competences : {{ GroupeOfCompetence.name }}
    <ul>    
        {% for competence in GroupeOfCompetence.competences %}   
        <input type="checkbox" name= {{ 'competence' ~ i }} value='{{ competence.name }}'> {{ competence.name }} <br>
        {% set i = i + 1 %}
        {% endfor %}    
    </ul>
    <br> <br>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

How should I set the name and value of the checkboxes to be able to get the checkboxes that are checked in the *'$request->getSession();'* object ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: var x=$("checkbox").is(":checked") if you use jQuery.
Or get them on the Request on your controller and then add them to your session.

Comment: Twig is for rendering. You should change your controller Action so that it builds an array with objects that hold all the data you need for rendering

Comment: Yes Frank B. But it would be too complicated. I hoped I could get the competences that are checked, and then build objects from these checked checkboxes, and then inject them in the relation between competences and the other entity (in my case the user) ...

Comment: Yes Albeis that could be a solution. But how do you set the name of each checkbox so you can know which competence is checked. And how do you send this information to the path of the action?

Comment: @zskiredj : The form send the values by name attribute  to the action url. On your controller, get the checkbox by name. $request->request->get('"checkbox name'),  for every checkbox,so,on Controller is where you have to check if a competence is checked.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple : use the id of the competence entity as its name !
To retrieve the object that is checked, I use then this id in the request object. No need to use Collections of forms or entities ...

Here is the code if it can help someone :

TWIG :

```
<form action="{{ path('app_profil_traitement_competences') }}" method="post">

{% for GroupeCompetence in GroupesCompetences %}
    nom groupe competence : {{ GroupeCompetence.nom }}
    <ul>    
    {% for competence in GroupeCompetence.competences %}     
    <input type="checkbox" name= '{{ competence.id }}' value='{{ competence.id }}'> {{ competence.nom }} <br>
    {% endfor %}    
    </ul>
        <br> <br>
{% endfor %}

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Symfony :

```
public function traiterCompetencesAction(Request $request)
    {

        for ($i=1;$i<10;$i++)
        {   
            if ($request->get($i) !== null)

            //... And here i have the id of the objects which are checked!!
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: In fact, if you are using POST method,  you should use $request->request->get($i).
Regards

Comment: @Albeis : $request->get($i) works because i m using $request as a parameter in the controller !! :=)

Comment: Ok! but you should specify it on your answer :) Regards